# Document queryselector-based variables in structured data via GTM keep returning 'undefined' in Rich Results Test

Tags: schema.org, google-tag-manager, structured-data, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

I use GTM queryselector variables to populate the JSON-LD structured data on my pages dynamically - or at least I'm trying to. The variables are pulled correctly in GTM preview mode, they render fine in Chrome Console, but they load as 'undefined' in Google Rich Results test! Here's an example:

[image: ![variable]
**Custom JS Variable**

[image: custom html]
**Structured Data JavaScript in GTM (custom HTML tag)**

[image: render]
**Render readout in Chrome Console**

[image: rich results]
**Rich Results: *undefined***

The site (https://thechartcast.com) is on WordPress and I'm wondering if some plugin could be messing with the Googlebot render, or something.

Comment: I'd also point out that the built-in variables for GTM, e.g. Page URL, are rendered perfectly fine in the Rich Results test, which leads me to believe that maybe something is  afoot with the dynamic rendering of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work yay! I installed a prerenderer WP plugin specifically for Googlebot ([prerender.io](https://prerender.io)) and switched around some of the variable selectors.